# Add Working hours to a DateTime field SQL

Tags: sql

I was wondering if there was a way to add a number of business hours to a DateTime field.

E.g. Add 8 hours

Real Time- 2016-05-11 15:00:00.000 = 2016-05-11 23:00:00.000

**Business Time-** 2016-05-11 15:00:00.000 = 2016-05-12 15:00:00.000

Thanks in advance!

Comment: tag the dbms being used.

Comment: Create a view with a new column that reflects this logic.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL you can try to build your own function. 
The normal function:

```
select dateadd(hh, 8, '2016-05-11 15:00:00.000')
```

Then you can build a scalar function (which does your logic with your specific business hours:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499%28v=sql.105%29.aspx